# Problems with renaming .cs properties in the solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, renaming

I am having trouble renaming my file from `T1_Khan_Saad` to `P1_Khan_Saad`. There is no option to rename when I right click in the solution explorer.

[image]

Comment: maybe you have to stop debug?

Comment: I rarely rename in VS editor.  Use commandline or Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the file icon in your screenshot, this is a **linked file** (note the little arrow at the lower right-hand corner). Visual Studio cannot directly rename linked files (which makes sense - they might be referenced by other projects as well).

What you can do is:

1. Remove the file from your project.
2. Rename it at its physical location using Windows explorer.
3. Re-link it to your project.

There's a uservoice entry for enabling this feature in Visual Studio:

- [Allow renamed linked files in solution explorer](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2842287-allow-renamed-linked-files-in-solution-explorer)

Comment: How do I re-link it?

Comment: @Saad: How did you add this link in the first place? Do the same again: Right-click the solution, add existing item, select the file, click the little error next to "Add" and choose "Add as link".

Comment: @Saad: Oh, and if you linked it by accident and just want to to be a regular project file: "Add" the file instead of "Add As Link", and you'll be able to rename it as well.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Its not a linked file anymore.